# Setting preferredContentSize value appears too late

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have modally presented view controller, which opens another view controller(let call it secondVC).
According to the design, the height of secondVC is greater than firstVC, I tried a lot to change the size of secondVC in several methods like:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            return self.tableView.contentSize
        }
        set {}
    }
```

OR

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize
    }
```

moreover I tried to set it before like:

```
let vc = SecondVC()
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500)
show(vc, sender: nil)
```

By setting **preferredContentSize** the height of my secondVC changes but too late and this animation looks very ugly.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

**preferredContentSize** is part of UIContentContainer protocol and is part of
**Responding to Changes in Child View Controllers** logic. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer)

**preferredContentSize** has effect only if VC has a parent controller (is child of a container view). You can check it by testing the "parent" property of the VC.

Comment: but at the end is it modal or part of a container like UINavigationController?

Comment: NavigationCotroller -> MainVC -> modally presents -> FirstVC -> SecondVC

Comment: check if secondVC has a parent